# How to optimize this HTML5 animation?

Tags: javascript, html5

I'm just learning the basics of animating with Javascript and HTML5. I'm trying to create this scrolling logos element for my site, and I'm pretty sure that my code is very inefficient. Can anyone give me any tips on how to do a better job of what I'm trying to do here?

http://jsbin.com/anagug/1/edit

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
        var ctx;
        var count = 0;
        var xpos;
        var ypos;
        var revealTimer;

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://www.firewalkcreative.com/2012/images/logos_1.png";

        function switchImage(){

            xpos = count * 150;
            ypos = 0;

            count++;
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
            revealTimer = setInterval(revealImage,100);

            if(count == 5)
                count = 0;

        }


        function revealImage() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 840, 90, xpos, count, 840, 90);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 840, 90, xpos-900, 0, 840, 90);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha += 0.1;
            if (ctx.globalAlpha >= 1.0)
                clearInterval(revealTimer);
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function init() {

            ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            setInterval(switchImage,3000);
        }
```

Comment: drawing objects is always going to be expensive. It would be much smoother to draw those elements before the timer function starts, so that you're not expending resources to draw every time the function fires every 5 seconds

Comment: I don't see any scrolling, only fading. Anyway, it may be because I'm not experienced with it, but I wouldn't use canvas for this.

Answer (score 2):

Always do a `clearInterval()` before doing a new `setInterval()` on the same variable. Doesn't matter if it has been cleared or not.

e.g.

```
clearInterval(revealImage);
revealTimer = setInterval(revealImage,100);
```

You're code has a bug where the `revealTimer` is being reset before being cleared.

Why do you need to reset it?

```
function init() {   
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    setInterval(switchImage,3000);
    setInterval(revealImage,100);
}
```

Should work just as well.